# Google Maps for Expression Engine

Tags: google-maps-for-ee, google-maps

Is it just me or is it very difficult to just pick this add-on up and get it working. I've been trying to follow the documentation on the site for a couple of hours now and I still can't get my first map to display. What I feel is missing from the docs is a simple "How-to" on setting up.

Sorry for the mini-rage but I've wasted a lot of time reading docs that just seem to get straight into using the tags but no intro or walkthrough for what you need to set up in your channel to get it working.

Comment: Which one? http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/google-maps or http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/mx-google-maps or http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/gmaps

Comment: @PeterLewis - From the title, I'm pretty sure he means ["Google Maps for Expression Engine"](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/google-maps).

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for the frustration. I put a lot of time into making things work properly, but it's sometimes hard to perceive parts of the documentation that are confusing for others (since it all makes sense to me). Appreciate the honest feedback and will definitely add a "Getting Starting" guide to the site.

Derek's post is good too, so be sure to follow all those steps.

I definitely want you to be satisfied and confident in Objective HTML products. If you have any other questions or complaints please don't hesitate to email [support@objectivehtml.com](http://support@objectivehtml.com).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post Justin, I got there in the end and am building out my site now. Sorry for my little rage, I come from the design side of things so what's fairly straight forward for a developer can sometimes be way over my head, but I am getting better. 

I'm running into a small problem however. Can you help me out with it?

Some entries aren't showing on my map while others are. in the back-end they all look like they are going in, (I get the preview) but on the site they are missing from the main map. The text fields etc from the entry show up but not the marker.

Comment: Sure thing. Just send me an email and I can best help you there.

Comment: Hi Justin, sent you a mail with a proper outline of what I'm seeing, my template & a screenshot of my channel fields. If you want me to set you up with access to that channel let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that Justin's docs make some assumptions and lack a proper "here's how to get started" explainer - but that's partially because his add-ons are all very powerful and can be used in so many different ways. His [examples section](https://objectivehtml.com/google-maps/examples) is the best place to start.

Here's how to get going in the most common circumstance (you want to plot a marker on a map in your entry).

1. Add a map field to your channel using the Google Maps fieldtype.
2. Create an entry where you plot one or more markers on the map.
3. Use the following code in your template.

...

```
{exp:gmap:init id="my_map" style="width:400px;height:300px"}
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel"}
    {my_map_field id="my_map"}          
{/exp:channel:entries}
```